# tf.Variable gets converted to normal tensor in loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a custom layer in Keras in which I define some variables to which I assign some values in the call section.

```
class Mine_layer(KL.Layer):
  def __init__(self,shape):
    self.block=tf.Variable(tf.constant(1,shape=shape))
  def call (self,indeces):
    self.block=self.block[indeces[0][0],indeces[0][1]].assign(1)
```

this works but if i try to utilize a for loop over all the indeces:

```
for i in tf.range(0,limit=tf.shape(indeces)[0]):
   self.block=self.block[indeces[i][0],indeces[i][1]].assign(1)
```

this gives me an error saying that "'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'".

Why does this happen? How can I solve it?

I tried looking at the documentation but I still don't get it.

Thanks in advance to anyone who may answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, we do not use self.block=... ever again after **init** because this could have a possibility that make self.block points to another undesirable object like a tensor in your case, resulting the error message.

i.e.

```
class my_layer(keras.Layer):
  def __init__(self,shape):
    self.block = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape)) #use tf.ones instead of tf.constant

  def call(self,inputs):
    self.block.scatter_nd_update(inputs,tf.ones(tf.shape(inputs)[0]))
    #remove the self.block= assignment and use scatter_nd_update

class my_layer2(keras.Layer):
  def __init__(self,shape):
    self.var = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape)) 

  def call(self,inputs):
     for i in tf.range(tf.shape(inputs)[0]):
        self.var[inputs[i,0],inputs[i,1]].assign(1)
```

Update: Both solutions are working

Comment: thank you but it didn't solve the issue when I try to use the assing it still tells me that Tensor has no attribute 'assign' even though the self.block should be a Variable

Comment: @Bomps What version of tensorflow are you using? I am using tf2.5.0 and can do this without any problem. As this kind of fancy indexing is a new feature, in older days, scatter_nd_update was used instead.

Comment: Same version as you

Comment: A thing I didn't mention that occurred to me is that inputs shape is none at graph creation time this is the reason why I'm using this `tf.range(0,limit=tf.shape(indeces)[0])` as with none it should set limit to 0

Comment: @Bomp please find my colab here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-GwUftCqrhXzcQVrjjPbwt_oy4cue7h4   It's working properly. There are two points to be careful. 1. What is inside the for i in tf.range(n) loop? If you only have the assign statement, that should be no problem. 2. can only use assign while assign_add won't work here

Comment: thank you for your time and effort I think I found the problem I will accept your answer as it was the root of the error even though there was another error coming from the initialization which I hadn't notice (and TensorFlow was strangely not complaining about)